# How to load feedItem?

Tags: migration, feeditem

I need to migrate feeditem data from my old org to new production. There are about 3,000,000 records (30 "lacks") in old org. Let me know is there any way to migrate it.

Comment: I am getting the following error while exporting the feeditems.batch failed: feature not enabled : binary field not supported

Comment: Small comment: I think lack is a regional expression of quanity which may not be clear to everyone. 1 lack = 100 000 ? may be easier to express differently.

Comment: If what @Sdry said is true, that would definitely make much more sense. I wasn't sure what you meant by "30 lacks".

Comment: @JesseAltman Its actually 30 lakhs.. 1 lakh = 100000.. More about it here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh

Answer (score 1):

Don't export the ContentData field - when migrating ContentPosts and ContentComments, you should already have migrated all the Files. Perhaps that will help?

Comment: David, if you aren't sure of your answer, maybe a comment is more appropriate?

Comment: The question mark is not that I am not sure of my answer - it is that I am not sure what, exactly, is being asked. The question is short, has zero supporting information, and spends most of its time dealing with an odd unit of measure.

Comment: I wanted to load migrate 'FeedItem' records but  when i load FeedItem (now feedpost) using data loader i am getting the error 'batch failed: feature not enabled : binary field not supported'.                                                         I am looking for an approach to load the Feedpost records.

Comment: FeedPost is not an object anymore. You should be loading into FeedItem, but (as I said) do not load the ContentData field AND you should have already loaded the ContentVersion records required.